# data-loading message on the button not working with ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have am making an ajax call to POST some data and it takes a long time to get the result. So I want a data-loading message on my button till my ajax request finishes. here is my javascript code.

```
$("#add").button('loading');
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    async: false,
    success: function(data) {
        $("#add").button('reset');
    }
});
```

Here is my button definition in my html page

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <button id="add" class=" btn btn-success btn-sm info" type="button" data-loading-text="Adding" onclick="create()">Add New</button>
</div>
```

If I comment out the AJAX call I can see the data loading message on the button but if allow the AJAX call to happen I can't see the data loading message. How can I make this work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because you're using `async: false`. This locks the browser until the request completes, hence the UI cannot be updated during this period. To solve the problem, remove `async: false`:

```
$("#add").button('loading');
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    success: function(data) {
        $("#add").button('reset');
    }
});
```

The use of `async: false` is considered to be terrible practice for this very reason. Its use should be avoided at all costs.

Comment: No problem, glad to help.